# Is it safe to rely on another library enum values?

Tags: java, architecture, enums

I am working on REST API and I need to inform client how things went and return a HTTP code.

In a `package org.springframework.http` there are very well created and documented HTTP status codes and maybe I would like to use them in my application.

From application design/structure perspective, is it safe to rely on such information and use it in own applications or is better to have own enum values in my situation?

Answer (score 2):

It's as safe as relying on any other public API.

Answer (score 1):

[Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20520869/982542) is basically correct. It is a public API, it is as safe as any other public API. However, if you are using `org.springframework.http` just for the http status, why don't you use native Java [Status](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html)? Not all status are mapped (they miss status `405` for instance) but it is core Java so you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't update library it is certainly safe.